# Finding the first occurrence where id don't match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I’m trying to find the first occurrence of SNum where the VerNum don’t match. In this case it should point to SNum = 300 as VerNum 12 is not present.

```
DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp1 (VerNum INT, SNum INT)

INSERT INTO #temp1 
VALUES (11,100), (12,100), (11,200), (12,200), (11,300)


CREATE TABLE #temp2 (VerNum INT)

INSERT INTO  #temp2 
VALUES (11), (12) 


SELECT * FROM #temp1
SELECT * FROM #temp2
```

A full join is not working, i can loop through the table and get the result I am after, but there must be a better way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
select top 1 snum 
from #temp1 
group by SNum
having count(*) < (select count(*) from #temp2) 
order by snum asc
```

This could work if you're sure that there are no duplicates `vernum` for the same `snum`

This by the way, i think is a more solid solution:

```
select top 1 coalesce(a.snum, b.snum) as result
from #temp1 a full join #temp1 b on a.SNum = b.SNum and a.VerNum <> b.VerNum
where a.VerNum is null or b.VerNum is null
```

I didn't test them much, only with the data you provided, so be careful!

Comment: I am running through to make sure there are no duplicates, but this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: With the second query there is no join to #temp2 I am not sure I fully understand it. the first seems to be more what I am looking for unless I am missing something.